# Force kill if gracefull shutdown fails

Tags: bash, kill

We have a bash script that can shut down our application specifically we have a stop function like this.

```
doStop(){
pid=`cat ${pidfile}`
echo "Gracefully terminating server with pid $pid"
kill ${pid}
echo "Server stopped"
}
```

However it is possible the kill will fail for various reasons and we want to for kill it like this...

```
kill -9 ${pid}
```

Is there a way to wait for kill to work and if it did not issue a kill -9?

Comment: probably `kill` itself will take its time. So after it you can write and ìf`condition to check if it is still running and proceed to -9 killing it.

Answer (score 1):

From `man`kill`

> kill - send a signal to a process

It means `kill` doesn't receive any response from the process. The only way to "wait" for the process is to check if the process exists for some period of time and to send him `kill -9` when time is out.

e.g (not tested)

```
doStop(){
  pid=$(cat ${pidfile})
  echo "Gracefully terminating server with pid $pid"
  kill ${pid}
  let count=60
  while [[ $count -ge 0 ]] && [[ -n "$(ps --pid ${pid} -o pid=)" ]]
  do
    sleep 1
    let "count--"
  done

  if [[ -n "$(ps --pid ${pid} -o pid=)" ]];
  then
    kill -9 ${pid}
  fi

  if [[ -n "$(ps --pid ${pid} -o pid=)" ]];
    then
    echo "Server stopped"
    exit 0
  else
    echo "Failed to stop server"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```